# What parameters could be considered to measure the coiling of a ring?

Tags: curvature, biophysics

I want to draw a phase diagram to quantify the coiling of a ring inside my system and I was wondering what parameters could be use to precisely define how coiled the ring is.

Currently I am modeling the ring as a regular curve and I am using the torsion and the curvature of the curve as the parameters. The ring exerts a force against the medium that contains it and I was considering this as a possible parameter because it seems to be proportional to the degree of coiling.

What are usual choices to measure the degree of coiling of a ring (inside a viscous medium like the inside of a cell)? Are there any references in the literature that I can be pointed to?

Comment: Try as I might, I can't quite imagine what the coiling of a ring looks like. Is it the transformation of a line segment into a circle? Can you include an image or a gif illustrating this process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mathematical description of a [plasmid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasmid) could help. This is a circular DNA, i.e. a double helical polymer closed on itself. Being double stranded, the polymer can be coiled, and the torsional stress "organizes" the global structure of the ring. Two numbers describe it: twist $Tw$ (turns of the helix around the axis) and writhe $Wr$ (turns of the axis around itself), their sum being the linking number $Lk=Tw+Wr$ (in the usual horrible two letter notation...).  Different conformations of the ring with equal linking number are topologically equivalent. See [DNA supercoiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNA_supercoil) for more details.

(The linking number of the DNA is tightly controlled by specialized [enzymes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topoisomerase) which continuously coil and uncoil the double helix to keep an average slightly *unwound* DNA, which is then more accessible to the other cellular machines)